# $PC+PD$ is least when the angles $CPA$ and $DPB$ are equal

Tags: triangles

$C$ and $D$ are two points in the $same$ side if a straight line $AB$ and $P$ is any point in $AB$. Show that $PC+PD$ is least when the angles $CPA$ and $DPB$ are equal

No idea how to solve this problem